# The Mountain has no insignia of his breast plate? What is his official role?

Tags: game-of-thrones

What is the Mountain's official role now?

The Mountain dresses like Kings Guard, yet he has no insignia (let alone 7-star insignia) on his breast plate. So, is his official title "*Kings Guard* who is protecting the king's mother but who does not wear an insignia like all the other *Kings Guard*"?

Remember Qyburn saved the Mountain from near death after his killing Prince Oberyn. He used steroids (or something) that made him even stronger. After Cersei's "*Walk of Atonement*", the Mountain picks her up and carried Cersei somewhere. There after, he is always following Cersei everywhere. What is his role?

Comment: King Brute. Lord o' Bones(crusher). Ser Robert Zombie. Cersei's Violence Provoker. High Sparrow's Dismay. The Mountain that Hypes.

Comment: Related: [Why is the Kingsguard still protecting Cersei?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/131769/21267)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the Mountain's official role now? The simple answer is: King's Guard. According to Qyburn in S5E10, "May I have the honor of presenting the newest member of the King's Guard," referring to the resurrected Mountain. Note the breastplate.

[image]

And Ser Jaime, in his King's Guard uniform in S5E2. Note the breastplate.

[image]

So, why is the new Mountain devoted only to Cersei? Because he swore it himself. We don't hear it in his own voice, but we get the gist from Qyburn. Again from S5E10, "If it please, your Grace, he has taken a holy vow of silence. He has sworn that he will not speak until all his Grace's enemies are dead," i.e. Cersei's enemies.

Comment: Good answer, only one problem, KG swears fealty to the King, not to his family. But afterwards, King or his regent may assign a KG to any task which may include guarding members of the royal family.

Comment: Or maybe the Mountain can't remove his armor. We don't know what he looks like underwear, so I (personaly) think that he's linked to it.

Comment: @Aegon you've got it wrong. "The Kingsguard, also known poetically as the White Swords or white cloaks, are the royal bodyguards of the Iron Throne. Supposedly the finest knights in the Seven Kingdoms, they are **sworn to protect their king and the royal family** with their own lives". Reference [Kingsguard](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Kingsguard)

Comment: @NikaG. Yes and their loyalty lies to their King and only their king (Which is actually part of their oath). No one else. Would you elaborate on what exactly did I got wrong?

Comment: Maybe you're confused because I did not use the explicit word "Sworn Shield". Viserys I assigned Ser Criston Cole, a Kingsguard as personal shield of Rhaenyra Targaryen. Later same KG was assigned to same task for Queen Alicent Hightower by the King. Similarly, King may take away that protection from any Royal member if he feels like it.

Comment: @Aegon KG is obliged to defend royal family. Its not just because the King wants so or assigns them to the task.

Comment: @nika yes they are sworn to defend the royal blood and they do serve as personal guard of a certain royal if the king commands. Gregor is acting as personal shield of cersei.

Comment: If Gregor wasn't personal shield of cersei, kg would take turns at guarding her. But gregor is the only one guarding her. By precedent of viserys I we know that's done by king's command

Comment: @Aegon For what its worth, it was Prince Rhaegar (not King Aerys) that ordered Ser Arthur Dayne to protect the Tower of Joy instead of fight in the Trident. KG might have to take orders from anyone in immediate royal family.

Comment: @konishiki Arthur Dayne was Rhaegar's best friend. While it is true, Princes can command KG (If the command does not violate their vows e.g. to forswear their loyalty to the king), Arthur Dayne's role in ToJ sequence was more than just duty.

Comment: Until her walk of atonement, Cersi had been guarded by Lannister soldiers, if i remember correctly. I hope this clears everything up nicely.

Comment: I disagree about Robert Strong's vow and that he swore anything. In the books, it's implied he is a semi-zombie, uncapable of uttering a word or of swearing anything. Maybe Qyburn controls him somehow. Ser Robert's "vow of silence" and his always wearing the helmet are parts of a ploy to hide his true identity as a reanimated ser Gregor, which is a secret (though not very well kept) in the books.

Comment: He's a member of the Kingsguard in appearance to make it convenient to explain his appearance and his following Circe around. However that's about the extent of his membership. Even before You Know What, he wasn't really one for worrying about duty, honor, oaths, that sort of thing. He is loyal to Circe before and afterward I would suspect that he has been inoculated to be completely slavishly loyal to her.